# How to get values without record key word in python await

Tags: python, async-await

When I call below python await database call.

```py
result = await db.connect(handlers.getFrmlryKeys(formulary))
```

I am getting below result set when displaying result

```py
>>> print(result)
[<Record frmlry_key=Decimal('109')>, <Record frmlry_key=Decimal('277')>, <Record frmlry_key=Decimal('284')>, <Record frmlry_key=Decimal('320')>, <Record frmlry_key=Decimal('346')>]
```

Is it possible to get/convert the result set like below?

```py
'109', '277', '284', '320', '346'
```

Answer (score 0):

I am able to resolve it by converting the "result" to dictionary object.

```
data = [dict(row) for row in result]
```

Hope this help someone who is new to python like me.